# find siblings by specific value of key in firebase node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing firebase app and I wanted to query inside a collection and fetch specific children (siblings) of a collection node.

See the screen shot.

How does a query for firebase to be defined to fetch them.

[image: Firebase Specific Children]

Need implementation in node js

thanks

Waqas

Answer (score 0):

Since firebase (unlike firestore) is pretty stripped in terms of querying, one way to do it is this:

*JavaScript*:

```
const fetchRestaurants = async () => {
    try {
        const ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
        const promises = ids.map(id => firebase.database().ref('/Restaurants/'+id).once('value').then(snap => snap.val()))
        const restaurants = await Promise.all(promises)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error fetching restaurants", error)
    }
}
```